# Reconcile raw data to register

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2x sheets - one "Register" and one "Summary" - and I need a VBA script which I can attach to a macro button, to match every cell in column O of Register (unique numbers) with column D on the Summary sheet.

If there is a match, I would like it to copy the cell in column L on the same row of the Summary sheet, as well as colour the row green, an paste that cell to column Q of the Register sheet - if there is a value in column Q already then to add it on top (as although the plan number on the Register sheet is unique, there could be multiple entries on the Summary sheet).

It would then loop to the next cell in column O to try and find the next match.

Comment: Try looping through the unique column and compare it via direct (another loop through the summary) or via `WorksheetFunction.Match`.
What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please understand that this is not a "*I tell what I want, and others do the work for me*" website. Therefore you need to show what you already have tried. [Edit] your question and add the code you have tried, tell us where exactly you got stuck or got any errors and which (and where in the code). Also reading [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) might help to improve your question.

Comment: Can't you just use `VLOOKUP` to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by add it on top? Could you show us an example?

Comment: Please check out the [tour] as well as [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question with more detail about **what you've tried** and what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you are asking:

```
Sub foo()
Dim RegisterLastRow As Long
Dim SummaryLastRow As Long
Dim UniqueLookUp As Variant
RegisterLastRow = Sheets("Register").Cells(Sheets("Register").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'get the last row with data in Register
SummaryLastRow = Sheets("Summary").Cells(Sheets("Summary").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get the last row with data in Summary

For x = 2 To RegisterLastRow 'loop through Register from row 2 to end (excluding headers)
    UniqueLookUp = Sheets("Register").Cells(x, 15).Value 'get the unique value from column 15 = Column O
    For y = 2 To SummaryLastRow 'loop through Summary from row 2 to end (to exclude headers)
        If Sheets("Summary").Cells(y, 4).Value = UniqueLookUp Then 'if values match
            Sheets("Summary").Cells(y, 4).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'color row in green
            Sheets("Register").Cells(x, 17).Value = Val(Sheets("Register").Cells(x, 17).Value) + Val(Sheets("Summary").Cells(y, 12).Value) 'add the values to column Q =17 on Register from Summary column L = 12
        End If
    Next y
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Thanking you immensely!